# psycopg2/SQLAlchemy: execute function with custom type array parameter

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, psycopg2

I have a custom postgres type that looks like this:

```
CREATE TYPE "Sensor".sensor_telemetry AS
(
    sensorid character varying(50),
    measurement character varying(20),
    val numeric(7,3),
    ts character varying(20)
);
```

I am trying execute a call to a postgres function that takes an array of this type as a parameter.

I am calling this function with SQLAlchemy as follows:

```
result = db.session.execute("""select "Sensor"."PersistTelemetryBatch"(:batch)""", batch)
```

where `batch` looks like:

```
{
    "batch" : [
        {
            "sensorID" : "phSensorA.haoshiAnalogPh",
            "measurement" : "ph",
            "value": 8.7,
            "timestamp": "2019-12-06 18:32:36"
        },
        {
            "sensorID" : "phSensorA.haoshiAnalogPh",
            "measurement" : "ph",
            "value": 8.8,
            "timestamp": "2019-12-06 18:39:36"
        }
    ]
}
```

When running this execution, I am met with this error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) can't adapt type 'dict'
```

I'm guessing that psycopg2 is complaining about the custom type array entry as a dict, because I can supply dictionaries as parameters to other pg function executions (but these dictionaries are not contained within an array like this case). Am I correct about this?

How do I go about correctly passing an array of these objects to my pg function?

Comment: Convert your dicts to tuples: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59031648/how-to-pass-an-array-of-customs-type-to-a-postgresql-function/59033340#59033340

Comment: using the code in your linked answer (the psycopg/literal response), the list of tuples looks like [('value', 'measurement', 'timestamp', 'sensorID'), ('value', 'measurement', 'timestamp', 'sensorID')]. Should I just be supplying the values of these keys here? Additionally, does the order of the values in each tuple need to be the same as the pgsql type I have created? @IljaEverilä

Comment: The tuples should contain the values, and they should reflect the order of fields of your user-defined-type. Come to think of it, this might be a nice use case for Python's `operator.itemgetter()`, which iirc returns tuples of values, if given multiple keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A straightforward way to pass the data is to [convert the list of dicts to a list of tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59031648/how-to-pass-an-array-of-customs-type-to-a-postgresql-function/59033340#59033340) in Python and let psycopg2 handle adapting those to suitable SQL constructs:

```
from operator import itemgetter

ig = itemgetter("sensorID", "measurement", "value", "timestamp")
batch = {"batch": list(map(ig, batch["batch"]))}
query = """
        SELECT "Sensor"."PersistTelemetryBatch"(
            CAST(:batch AS "Sensor".sensor_telemetry[]))
        """
result = db.session.execute(query, batch)
```

Another interesting option when your data is a list of `dict` would be to use `json_populate_record()` or `json_populate_recordset()`, but for those you'd have to fix the keys to match:

```
import json

batch = [{"sensorid": r["sensorID"], 
          "measurement": r["measurement"],
          "val": r["value"],
          "ts": r["timestamp"]}
         for r in batch["batch"]]
batch = {"batch": json.dumps(batch)}

query = """
        SELECT "Sensor"."PersistTelemetryBatch"(ARRAY(
            SELECT json_populate_recordset(
                       NULL::"Sensor".sensor_telemetry,
                       :batch)))
        """
result = db.session.execute(query, batch)
```